# How to store and use parameters in a pipeline stack creation for later serverless stack creations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I have a serverless app on AWS that I am deploying using Cloudformation. I deploy the pipeline first using a pipeline.yml file, which creates the 'pipeline' stack (which populates the repo with code from an s3 bucket) and then runs it. This then creates the 'dev' stack using a seperate YAML file called template.yml in the newly created repo which contains the infrastructure for the lambdas, dbs, and other resources contained to make this app work. After a review, a developer can then release this to the 'prod' environment. The reason it is split it out like this is so that the pipeline gets created once, and the dev/prod environment stacks can be initiated multiple times.

In it's current state, there are parameters hardcoded within the template.yml that are used in dev/prod stack creation. Problem is, the user has to manually change these hardcoded values in the file before stack creation. Is there any way the user can edit these parameters as usual in the UI where I create the pipeline stack, and these parameters would bubble into the app/environment stack creation?

If my question does not make sense, I can definitely help further clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Do you by "pipeline" refer to Codepipeline? If so, you can pass parameters and parameter overrides from the Codepipeline to the app stack (template.yml). I can provide a more comprehensive answer and example if you confirm that it's a Codepipeline.

Comment: Yup! I am indeed referring to Codepipeline!